# how to draw draggable direction using encoded overview polylines

Tags: google-maps

I want to draw drag gable route on Google map using encoded poly line string.So that i can drag route , make changes in it and save in database. can anyone have idea regarding this?????
ex: I have following encoded polyline

```
var encodedPath='iqgnAa|lxMDq@@]j@CrIKhBClEIrFMe@oCCKBa@VqAbAqCEWIi@MSg@[oAu@kAu@aAe@{@WcAScA]g@Mm@EaAV_ECKxBl@BL@FDKpB';

var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath( encodedPath );
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 8
    });
    polyline.setMap( map );
```

I want to draw drag gable path on Google map using this encoded poly line path.
Currently i am able to draw poly line on Google map using following code but its is not drag gable
Any suggestions???? 
also i want draggable behavior like Google map direction service so that i can deviate the existing path and save for future use

Answer (score -1):

You can make it draggable in the constructor

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 8,
        draggable: true
    });
```

or later as

```
polyline.setDraggable(true);
```

or

```
polyline.set('draggable',true);
```

If you use the polyline to render Google's direction services, the paths will be updated along with the polyline when you drag it. Keep in mind that after doing this you will need to persist the new polyline path to the database. This is done by adding listeners to the polyline path

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline.getPath(), 'set_at', function () {
    var encodedpath=google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath( polyline.getPath() );
    SaveMyPath(encodedpath);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polyline.getPath(), 'insert_at', function () {
    var encodedpath=google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath( polyline.getPath() );
    SaveMyPath(encodedpath);
});
```

It's up to you to build the function `SaveMyPath`

Comment: thanks for reply. But by using draggable feature of polyline when i drag path it drags entire path but it doesnt give draggable feature like direction ren